# Is this proper way of extending classes in java?

Tags: java, interface, subclass, superclass

So I am making a game in LWJGL 2 and my project has 4 classes (Entity,AliveEntity,Player,Tree). I want my entities(e.g. trees, ferns,some items) to extend Entity class and player to extend Entity and AliveEntity at the same time so player can have hp, velocity, equipment, etc. So it looks like this now:

```
    public class Entity{

            public Entity(){ }

    public void methodForEveryEntity(){ }
    }


    public class AliveEntity extends Entity{

       public AliveEntity(){ super(); }

    public void methodForOnlyLivingEntities(){ }
    }


    public class Player extends AliveEntity{

       public Player(){ super(); }

        //it can use methods from AliveEntity and Entity classes
    }


    public class Tree extends Entity{

       public Tree(){ super(); }

        //only methods from Entity class
    }
```

Is my approach is correct? If no, then can you tell me what is the best way of doing this? I thought about Interfaces but I am not a big fan of them...

Comment: I'd say it looks good.

Comment: In general interfaces are useful when you want to work with models and classes are useful when you want to work with specific category of a model. For example if I want to work with birds I use an interface and if I want to work only with eagles I use a class. Considering the code snippet from description I think Entity fits better to an Interface rather  than a class unless in your use case you need to have an instance of a plain Entity (something like `Entity entity = new Entity()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge this seem to be correct when extending. When ever I need to I like to think of it in the manner of hierarchy. Does the extending follow it? Both **Tree** and **AliveEntity** are part of **Entity**, and **Player** is a part of **AliveEntity** though not part of **Tree** hence it only extends to **AliveEntity** . Hope this helps.